# The 'if' function not performing the code straight away

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

```
    import SpriteKit

func +(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

func -(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
}

func *(point: CGPoint, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: point.x * scalar, y: point.y * scalar)
}

func /(point: CGPoint, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: point.x / scalar, y: point.y / scalar)
}

#if !(arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64))
func sqrt(a: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
  return CGFloat(sqrtf(Float(a)))
}
#endif

extension CGPoint {
  func length() -> CGFloat {
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y)
  }
  
  func normalized() -> CGPoint {
    return self / length()
  }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
  
  struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let none      : UInt32 = 0
    static let all       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let monster   : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let projectile: UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
    
  }
  
  // 1
  let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
  var monstersDestroyed = 0
  var scorelabel: SKLabelNode?
  var playerscore = 0
    var ammocount = 30
    var ammoLabel: SKLabelNode?
  
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // 2
    backgroundColor = SKColor.white
    // 3
    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * -0.45, y: size.height * -0.49+20)
    // 4
    addChild(player)
    
    scorelabel = childNode(withName: "scoreLabel") as? SKLabelNode
    ammoLabel = childNode(withName: "ammoLabel") as? SKLabelNode
    
    physicsWorld.gravity = .zero
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(
      SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run(addMonster),
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
        ])
    ))
    
    
    let backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "music.caf")
    backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = true
    addChild(backgroundMusic)
      }
  
  func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
  }
  
  func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max - min) + min
  }
  
  func addMonster() {
    // Create sprite
    let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")
    
    monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: monster.size) // 1
    monster.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true // 2
    monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.monster // 3
    monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.projectile // 4
    monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none // 5
    
    // Determine where to spawn the monster along the Y axis
    let actualY = random(min: -frame.size.height/2+monster.size.height, max: frame.size.height/2-monster.size.height)
    
    // Position the monster slightly off-screen along the right edge,
    // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + monster.size.width/2, y: actualY)
    
    // Add the monster to the scene
    addChild(monster)
    
    // Determine speed of the monster
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(5.0), max: CGFloat(10.0))
    
    monster.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    // Create the actions
    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: size.width * -0.5, y: actualY), duration: TimeInterval(actualDuration))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let loseAction = SKAction.run() { [weak self] in
      guard let `self` = self else { return }
      let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        
        
        
        let gameOverScene = MenuScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene")
        print("lost")
        gameOverScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene!, transition: reveal)
        
        
    }
    monster.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, loseAction, actionMoveDone]))
    
    
  }
  
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // 1 - Choose one of the touches to work with
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
      return
    }
    run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("throwingsound.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
    
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    
    // 2 - Set up initial location of projectile
    let projectile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lazer")
    projectile.position =  CGPoint(x: size.width * -0.45, y: size.height * -0.49+20)
    
    projectile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: projectile.size.width/2)
    projectile.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    projectile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.projectile
    projectile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.monster
    projectile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none
    projectile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    
    // 3 - Determine offset of location to projectile
    let offset = touchLocation - projectile.position
    
    // 4 - Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
    if offset.x < 0 { return }
    
    // 5 - OK to add now - you've double checked position
    addChild(projectile)
    ammocount -= 1
    ammoLabel?.text = "ammo: \(ammocount)"
    
    // 6 - Get the direction of where to shoot
    let direction = offset.normalized()
    
    // 7 - Make it shoot far enough to be guaranteed off screen
    let shootAmount = direction * size.width*2
    
    // 8 - Add the shoot amount to the current position
    let realDest = shootAmount + projectile.position
    
    // 9 - Create the actions
    projectile.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    
    let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: realDest, duration: 3)
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    projectile.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
    
  }
  
  func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: SKSpriteNode, monster: SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Hit")
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()
    
    
    playerscore += 1
    scorelabel?.text = "Score: \(playerscore)"
    
    if ammocount < 25 {
      let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        let gameOverScene = MenuScene(fileNamed: "MenuScene")
        gameOverScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        view?.presentScene(gameOverScene!, transition: reveal)
    }
  }
}

extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // 1
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
      firstBody = contact.bodyA
      secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
      firstBody = contact.bodyB
      secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    
    // 2
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.monster != 0) &&
      (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.projectile != 0)) {
      if let monster = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
        let projectile = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {
        projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: projectile, monster: monster)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the if function when ammo count is below 25 does not execute the code straight away. It performs the code after a few seconds of ammocount going below 25. This code is an adaption of a tutorial I found online. Thank you for any help. I am adding these words as it says my post needs more details I will provide more details if someone asks tho.

Comment: Where is this code?

Comment: Please show how you call this code and how you update `ammocount`.

Comment: @Sweeper  I have updated my post with all of the code from my game scene.

Comment: Your "if" statement needs to be in the update function (update function doesnt seem to be in your code, you need to add it in), not the func projectileDidCollideWithMonster.